# Dont understand how to make flux subscription working in kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm new to reactive programming. I expect to see

```
test provider started
Beat 1000
Beat 2000
```

in logs but there is only `test provider started` and no `Beat` or `on complete` messages. Looks like I miss something

```
@Service
class ProviderService {

    @PostConstruct
    fun start(){
        val hb: Flux<HeartBeat> = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map { HeartBeat(it) }
        val provider = Provider("test", hb)
    }

}
////////////////////////

open class Provider(name: String, heartBests: Flux<HeartBeat>) {
    companion object {
        val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Provider::class.java)!!
    }

    init {
        log.info("$name provider started")
        heartBests.doOnComplete { log.info("on complete") }
        heartBests.doOnEach { onBeat(it.get().number) }
    }

    fun onBeat(n: Number){
        log.info("Beat $n")
    }
}

/////
class HeartBeat(val number: Number)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code lambda from 'doOnComplete' has been never called, because you created infinite stream. Method 'doOnEach' as 'map' is intermediate operations (like `map` in streams), its doesn't make a call. 
And you have another mistake, reactive suggests "fluent pattern".

Try this simple example:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import java.time.Duration

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val flux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map { HeartBeat(it) }

    println("start")

    flux.take(3)
            .doOnEach { println("on each $it") }
            .map { println("before map");HeartBeat(it.value * 2) }
            .doOnNext { println("on next $it") }
            .doOnComplete { println("on complete") }
            .subscribe { println("subscribe $it") }

    Thread.sleep(5000)
}

data class HeartBeat(val value: Long)
```

Comment: What makes actual call?

Comment: In example above it makes subscribe

Answer (score 3):

three pretty common mistakes here:

- operators like `doOnEach` return a new `Flux` instance with the added behavior, so you need to (re)assign to a variable or use a fluent style
- nothing happens until you `subscribe()` (or a variant of it. `blockXXX` do also `subscribe` under the hood for instance...)
- such a pipeline is fully asynchronous, and runs on a separate `Thread` due to the time dimension of the source, `interval`. As a result, control would immediately return in `init` even if you had subscribed, potentially causing the main thread and then the app to exit.

Comment: Thanks for good points. I think your comment will save me a lot of time